# Cannot send a HTTP request because the request gets aborted. "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, dotnet-httpclient, azure-virtual-machine

I'm currently developing a C# web application that uses Invoice Ninja's API to check for payment / invoice information. I've managed to get it working in my local machine using HttpClient, but whenever it's deployed to the deployment server (Windows Azure VM), I get the following error:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

The error is the same for both sites with and without SSL enabled (the dev site doesn't have one, while the live site does).

I've tried using the following solutions:

Adding `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;` before creating the HttpClient.

Using

```
WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler(); 
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler)) {
     //Code goes here
}
```

Manually adding the certificate to the `WebRequestHandler` from

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection collection = store.Certificates;
```

All other HTTP calls (Twilio, Authy, SendGrid) I've been doing inside the application work as intended, but calling Invoice Ninja has me stumped.

I'm not entirely sure where to go from here, and any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I've made a simple console app to check if it was IIS that was messing with the Http calls, but unfortunately the same thing still happens. I'm still getting the "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." error.

Could this potentially be a server configuration issue of some sort?

Edit 2: I tried running the console test app on a different VM, and it runs properly there. I'm even more unsure of where to go from here.

Here's the code I've tried, just in case it helps.

```
public static async Task<string> CallInvoiceNinja()
{
    var resultString = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
             client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://app.invoiceninja.com");
             client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Ninja-Token", "[TOKEN]");

             var result = await client.GetAsync("/api/v1/payments");
             resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       resultString = ex.Message;
       if(ex.InnerException != null)
       {
            resultString += "\n" + ex.InnerException.Message;
       }
     }

     return resultString;
}
```

Comment: tried adding `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;` ?

Comment: Try to debug with System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; //Do not use Tls10 and SSL3 - they are outdated and insecure

Comment: @VytautasPlečkaitis, I've tried it again, but unfortunately the call still gets aborted.

Comment: @vibs2006, I've already tried it, to no avail, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was looking at the problem the wrong way.

I did some more poking around and attempted to open the Swagger documentation for their API in IE on the server, and found out that it was being caused by our server not having the necessary cipher suites required by Invoice Ninja, since our server was apparently using a custom list of cipher suites.

I added the cipher suite that the API was using, and restarted the VM. I still needed the `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |=SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` line for the web app, but other than that, the issue is practically fixed.